# IndexPrimaryShardNotAllocatedException error while trying to close an elasticsearch cluster

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

After installing elasticsearch on my machine using https://gist.github.com/wingdspur/2026107 which starts an elasticsearch cluster at `http://localhost:9200`, I am trying to create an index with settings and used this code:

```
  search_indices.create index: 'test'
  search_indices.refresh index: 'test'
  search_indices.close index: 'test'
  search_indices.put_settings(index: 'test', **my_index_settings)
  search_indices.put_mapping(index: 'test', **my_mapping_settings)
  search_indices.open index: 'test'
```

Where

```
search_indices = Elasticsearch::Client.new({host: 'http://localhost:9200'}).indices
# this module comes from the elasticsearch-ruby gem
```

When I execute this code, I get an error when I try to execute the 'close' method (line 3 above)

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::Conflict:
   [409] {"error":"IndexPrimaryShardNotAllocatedException[[test_1] primary not allocated post api]","status":409}
```

I have tried adding the refresh method (line 2 above) which sometimes work and sometimes doesn't, I have a feeling that 'sometimes working' means I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I stumbled upon the cluster health option with the ruby API now it seems to work.

Here is how I solved it:

```
def search_client
  # I should memoize this so I don't have to keep creating new indices
  @search_client ||= Elasticsearch::Client.new({host: 'http://localhost:9200'})
end

def search_indices
  search_client.indices
end
```

Then my code above looks like:

```
  search_indices.create index: 'test'
  search_client.cluster.health wait_for_status: 'green'
  search_indices.close index: 'test'
  search_indices.put_settings(index: 'test', **my_index_settings)
  search_indices.put_mapping(index: 'test', **my_mapping_settings)
  search_indices.open index: 'test'
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Just as an FYI, you don't need to close an index to change the settings/mappings.  Open/Close is really only for archiving old data that you want to keep, but don't need actively searchable.

Comment: @Zach unless you are registering new analyzers in the put settings call, in which case you do need to close and reopen the index. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html

Comment: I'm not sure if this works, of if the time lapse is just long enough so that I don't see the error anymore. In any case, this seems like the only viable solution I've found.